# Sending email from excel automatically based on date

Tags: vba, excel

So I have code that sends a specific email to a distribution list on a specific date. Range("R19") has the date value. It's working when I clicked the run button. But I'm not sure if it will automatically work when the date value changes.

```
Sub Send_Monthly()

Set senddate = Worksheets("MONTHLY REMINDER").Range("R19")

If senddate.Value = Date Then

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments

oEmail.Close olSave

oEmail.HTMLBody = "<html>Hello World.</htmlcenter>" 
oEmail.Save
oEmail.To = "clients@abc.com"
oEmail.Importance = 2
oEmail.Subject = "REMINDER" & " " & Format(Now, "mmmm yyyy")
oEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "support@abc.com"
oEmail.Display

Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: *automatically work when the date value changes.* - place in the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to run when a certain cell changes, put this in a `Worksheet_Change` event.  In the worksheet you want to run this on, put the code, with some small adjustments:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim sendDate As Range
Dim oApp As Object, oEmail As Object, olMailItem As Object
Dim colAttach, olSave, oAttach

Set sendDate = Worksheets("MONTHLY REMINDER").Range("R19")
' I'm assuming you only want this to run if the value changes is `sendDate`
If target.address <> sendDate.address Then Exit Sub

If sendDate.Value = Date Then

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments

oEmail.Close olSave

oEmail.HTMLBody = "<html>Hello World.</htmlcenter>"
oEmail.Save
oEmail.To = "clients@abc.com"
oEmail.Importance = 2
oEmail.Subject = "REMINDER" & " " & Format(Now, "mmmm yyyy")
oEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "support@abc.com"
oEmail.Display

Set oEmail = Nothing
Set colAttach = Nothing
Set oAttach = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this has potential to fail if the another cell is changed and happens to equal the date in `R19`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - is that by virtue of the macro, or how I did the `target` part? I updated that to be `If target.address <> sendDate.address Then Exit Sub`

Comment: that works now. I think `If Target.Address = $R$19` at the very beginning is easier to read and follow and doesn't execute ANY code if the target doesn't match ... but that may just be a preferred style :)

Comment: So this will automatically work even though I won't click the run or open the excel sheet?

Comment: You have to have the sheet open. Afterall, you're changing a value on that sheet, right?  As long as cell `R19` in "Monthly Reminder" sheet is changed, your macro will run.

Comment: is there anyway I won't need to open the sheet? That it would automatically send like a recurring email

Comment: @astropringles - If you can somehow change that cell value, without opening the sheet, then it should still run.

Comment: it has a formula to change every month. Alright I'll give it a try, I'll check this as the answer, once it works by april. Thanks!

Comment: @BruceWayne can I have 2 worksheet_change in 1 excel file?

Comment: @astropringles - as far as I know, yes, each sheet can have one.  However, for each sheet you can only have one `Worksheet_Change` sub, so you'd want to put all your code under that single sub. Does that make sense?